# Create AMQP queue in exchange with Alpakka

Tags: akka, amqp, alpakka

I want to create a queue within an existing exchange for reading.

Another application is publishing messages to this exchange and fanning them out to all member queues. I want my new application to be an additional subscriber to these messages.

The following creates a queue:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val executionCtx: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher

val queueName: String = s"test-queue-${System.currentTimeMillis}"
val queueDeclaration = QueueDeclaration(queueName, autoDelete = true)
val amqpSource = AmqpSource(
    NamedQueueSourceSettings(AmqpConnectionUri(amqpUri), queueName)
      .withDeclarations(queueDeclaration), bufferSize = 10)
```

And this creates a sink for an exchange

```
val sink = AmqpSink.simple(AmqpSinkSettings(AmqpConnectionUri(amqpUri))
  .withExchange("exchange_name"))
```

But I'm not sure how to use them together, if that's the right approach.

Comment: could you please clarify your end goal? You just mentioned you want to create a queue within an exchange. What do you want to do with this queue?

Comment: Added the second paragraph to clarify intent. @StefanoBonetti

Comment: Have you read http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/latest/amqp.html#using-pub-sub-with-an-amqp-server ? Please try creating a source as described in that section, and if it doesn't work, describe what failed.

Comment: Also, take a look at the tests for the Alpakka connectors if you need more extensive examples https://github.com/akka/alpakka/tree/master/amqp/src/test/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/amqp

Comment: Thanks @StefanoBonetti, the examples were helpful. What I needed was `TemporaryQueueSourceSettings` instead of `NamedQueueSourceSettings`, as the former allows for an exchange name.